# Proof of vector addition and additive inverse. Confusing step.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading this in my text:

[image]

[image]

What is the point of doing $0 + u = -v$ and $u + 0 = -v$

More importantly, why is $ u + 0 = 0 $ categorized as the additive inverse property here:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It does seem superfluous:  just go from $0+u=-v$ to $u=-v$ and be done. The only explanation I could see is if the $\mathbf{0}$ is assumed to be only a one-sided identity.

Comment: My guess is that the axioms of vector space in your notes/textbook only include $u+0=u$ and not $0+u=u$, so you have to use commutativity.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the snip of the definition of vector space in OP's text.

Comment: @Wojowu  I had the same thought, but if this is true, they seem to have defined right-zeros but left inverses.

Comment: How does the commutative property help you get to the additive identity below?

Comment: Regarding the other question: the thing on the right expresses what axiom was used when passing from the previous line to the current one. In here, the "additive inverse" refers to replacing (v+(-v)) by 0 on the left.

Comment: ohhhh the additive inverse refers to the replacing of v + -v with 0 right?

Answer (score 1):

They're trying to be as explicit as possible. One could easily well question the point of proving something so "obvious", but the point of such proofs is a careful awareness of the particular properties at work at each step.

Pay attention and good luck in your studies.